# display data in promise call with vuejs and fetch()

Tags: vue.js, promise, fetch

I'm littlebit confused about the fetch function, this is my code:

```
<template>
  <!-- above the fold -->
  <section class="uk-section uk-section-primary">
    <div class="uk-container">
      {{ items }}
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- end above the fold -->
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src

export default {
  name: 'Home',

  data() {
    return {
        items: {}
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getInfo()
  },

  methods: {
    getInfo() {
      fetch('mydomain.net/cockpit/api/singletons/get/frontpage' , {
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer xxmySecretxx' }
      })
        .then(res => this.items = res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res));
    }
  },

}
</script>
```

In console.log I can view the items value, but on the browser the result is `[object Promise]` how fetch() works?

Comment: Try reading the documentation on fetch :
for example : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

res.json() is an async function as fetch; this is why you add the second "then". if you edit the code like below, you will get what you need:

```
    getInfo() {
      fetch('mydomain.net/cockpit/api/singletons/get/frontpage' , {
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer xxmySecretxx' }
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => this.items = res);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In a very simple manner all you really do is call fetch with the URL you want, by default the Fetch API uses the GET method, so a very simple call would be like this:

```
fetch(url) // Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
.then(function() {
    // Your code for handling the data you get from the API
})
.catch(function() {
    // This is where you run code if the server returns any errors
});
```

The fetch() method is modern and versatile. It’s not supported by old browsers, but very well supported among the modern ones.

The basic syntax is:

```
let promise = fetch(url, [options])
```

> url – the URL to access.
>
> options – optional parameters: method, headers etc.

Without options, that is a simple GET request, downloading the contents of the url.

The browser starts the request right away and returns a promise that the calling code should use to get the result.

The promise rejects if the fetch was unable to make HTTP-request, e.g. network problems, or there’s no such site. Abnormal HTTP-statuses, such as 404 or 500 do not cause an error.

We can see HTTP-status in response properties:

status – HTTP status code, e.g. 200.
ok – boolean, true if the HTTP status code is 200-299.